# Errors after npm audit fix angular 10.0.1

Tags: angular, angular10, npm-audit

I ran this older 10.0.1 angular project today, and it told me it had a lot of low vulnerabilities and a few high ones. so i ran npm audit fix to fix them.
but now when I try to run it, it gives me these errors:

```
Error: ./src/main.ts  
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
TypeError: angularCompiler.getResourceDependencies(...) is not a function or its return value is not iterable
    at getDependencies (C:\Web\vgc\vgc\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:261:56)
    at C:\Web\vgc\vgc\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:374:20
    at analyzingFileEmitter (C:\Web\vgc\vgc\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:307:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)



Error: ./src/polyfills.ts  
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
TypeError: angularCompiler.getResourceDependencies(...) is not a function or its return value is not iterable
    at getDependencies (C:\Web\vgc\vgc\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:261:56)
    at C:\Web\vgc\vgc\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:374:20
    at analyzingFileEmitter (C:\Web\vgc\vgc\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:307:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I couldn't really find any relatable problems or solutions online.

Comment: `nom audit fix` updates dependencies. Sometimes updated libraries are not compatible with other libraries or with your angular setup. Make sure you are using correct webpack version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it indeed had to do something with compatibility problems. I updated the webpack library which fixed it but gave me some more pretty unexplickable errors. I tried fixing it for a bit but in the end I did the smart thing and saved myself the hassle by just copying everything over to a new clean project which works fine now.

Comment: It always solves the problem, doesn't it?  @rtman

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. It started happening after installing `tailwind` on a fresh NX installation, I tried installing both `4` and `5` of webpack versions. no luck so far, any advice here? thanks.

Comment: I also noticed that `webpack` version didn't change after the installation of the package mentioned above, so it might be something else. webpack version: `4.43.0`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Upgrading the Angular CLI from 10 to 11 works for me.

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
ng update
```

Comment: Updating to Angular 11 also solved the issue for me. Note that the command above will always update to the newest version

Comment: Perfect after doing a lot of things this works for me.

Comment: This did work for me, on reflection however, I should have tried tried Darshan's answer first of removing installed packages and doing a fresh package install. Fortunately, I do not have any other angular projects to be concerned about.

Comment: It's not really an option when you have to keep the Angular version constant to maximise inter-project compatibility of components

Answer (score 6):

TRY this one

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
npm run build
```

Comment: You may also do `npm start` or any of your build script (instead of `npm run build`), which builds or serves your app.

Answer (score 2):

I have also fixed the same issue. The main reason was the "@angular-devkit/build-angular" version which is not matching in my case. I changed it's version compatible angular version. In my case I am using angular 10 and previously the version started with "0.11" and I changed it to "0.1002.3".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rmdir /s node_modules
npm install "or" npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular
npm run build
```

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.
What I did to successfully fix the problem:

1. git restore package-lock.json
2. git restore package.json
3. rm -rf node_modules/
4. npm install
5. npm start

The reasons of the steps:
1.2. steps to restore the origin package file
3 step to delete all the installed dependencies
4 step to install the dependencies again
after all, it restores to the origin status, it works.

Answer (score 1):

My clients make us be on a certain version, that they have approved. This is v10 for me.

I ran the below to solve this issue, after I inspected the [appropriate package.json](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/10.2.5/package.json)

```
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1002.0 @angular-devkit/architect@0.1002.0 @angular-devkit/build-optimizer@0.1002.0 @angular-devkit/core@10.2.0 @angular-devkit/schematics@10.2.0 --save
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this problem by Upgrading the Angular CLI version from 10 to 11. as #Craig answer.

or else, remove node_modules, package-lock.json file.

restore old package.json file and then run npm install. or don't do npm audit fix.

npm audit fix upgrades/modifies package dependencies, that's so made error.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force
```

I tried this before but that does not allow to update in windows os

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

or

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty
```

that's problem create beacuse of .\Temp\ng-fmB0C2\angular-errors.log

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all of the above, have to do an extra step:

- check if there is a duplicate versions of webpack, don't know how it was introduced though. The tree looked:

+-- @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.0.0
`-- webpack@5.36.2`   -- webpack@5.36.2

If so, fixed by( https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-dedupe ):

npm dedupe

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by

```
"preserveSymlinks": true,
```

missing from the `angular.json` in the options for my build.

Answer (score -1):

In my case problem gone resolved after installing the below package.

> **npm install @ngtools/webpack**

Answer (score -1):

For my case, I ran ng update @angular/cli@^11 @angular/core@^11

Then install webpack@4 since other package has dependencies on it.

Then install tapable & @types/webpack since webpack 4 plugin needs it.

.. and few times remove node_modules & npm install :)

Comment: Hello. Can we see your error logs? That would help shine light on the problem you are facing.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your concern. My problem is solved by now. Tq again