# Ng serve Error after updating to Angular 11

Tags: angular

I updated my Angular app to 11

```
Package                            Version
----------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1102.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.1102.10
@angular-devkit/core               11.2.10
@angular-devkit/schematics         11.2.10
@angular/cdk                       11.2.10
@angular/cli                       11.2.10
@angular/material                  11.2.10
@angular/material-moment-adapter   11.2.10
@schematics/angular                11.2.10
@schematics/update                 0.1102.10
rxjs                               6.6.7
typescript                         4.2.4
```

But, once I try to do a ng serve I get the below error

```
Error: ./src/main.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
TypeError: angularCompiler.getNextProgram is not a function
    at angularCompiler.analyzeAsync.then
```

I tried the suggestion mention here  [Errors after npm audit fix angular 10.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849026/errors-after-npm-audit-fix-angular-10-0-1)  but didnt help.
Wondering if I am missing something here.

Comment: Did you run `ngcc` on your node_modules after installation?

Comment: @31piy I tried  "ngcc": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser main module --async false --first-only",
    "postinstall": "npm run ngcc" but it didnt work aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue was with ivy .It works for now if I disable it  `"enableIvy": false`  in `angularCompilerOptions` within `tsconfig.app.json`

Answer (score 3):

I faced exactly the same problem but I wouldn't disable ivy. If `@angular/compiler` and `@angular/compiler-cli` has been updated to the version `12.0.0-rc.0`, You need to downgrade them to the latest stable version `11`, Also `typescript` to the version `4.1.5`.

This worked for me.

`npm install @angular/compiler@^11.2.12 @angular/compiler-cli@^11.2.12 typescript@4.1.5`

**17 May 2021 Update:**

The v12 is stable and has been officially released by Angular on 13 May 2021, So you can use the [official guide](https://update.angular.io/?v=11.0-12.0) to upgrade to v12 and this error will be fixed. Or simply you can use this command to upgrade to v12:

`ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12`

and in case of using angular material, you can use this command to update it too:

`ng update @angular/material`

The detailed information can be found in the provided link.

Comment: This solution does not work for me - it breaks dependencies in @angular/core during compilation.

Comment: As per v12 stable release of Angular, If you upgrade the Angular app to v12, It will work fine