# TypeError: angularCompiler.getNextProgram is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11, angular-ivy

I'm using angular 11.2 in my machine and I want to run a angular 12 project. After clone from git, I ran below commands.

1. `npm install`
2. `ng serve`

But I got below errors and can't run the project.
I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849026/errors-after-npm-audit-fix-angular-10-0-1) but it not worked for me.

```
Error: ./src/main.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
TypeError: angularCompiler.getNextProgram is not a function
    at C:\Users\thimira_p\Desktop\itrd\epic-itrda-web\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:376:100
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

Error: ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
TypeError: angularCompiler.getNextProgram is not a function
    at C:\Users\thimira_p\Desktop\itrd\epic-itrda-web\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:376:100
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

Error: (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0&sockPath=/sockjs-node
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
TypeError: angularCompiler.getNextProgram is not a function
    at C:\Users\thimira_p\Desktop\itrd\epic-itrda-web\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:376:100
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Angular 12 is the newest version, but still in "beta version"

Comment: Angular CLI: 12.0.0-rc.1
Node: 14.15.5
Package Manager: npm 6.14.11
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.0.0-rc.1.... this is the version show at project when I run "ng v" command. How do I change stable version my project

Comment: Got into the same thing. Did you find what the problem was, or fix it?

Comment: @Vee6 - I thing reason is cli & node version low than project. Remove node @ cli and install "node 14.16.1 cli 11.2.12". clone new project & ''npm install". I recommend use stable angular version.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I ended up going back to angular 11

Comment: Angular 12 released nowadays! I have the same problem

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem in an Angular app which uses a **custom** **webpack.config** - having `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` as a dependency.

**Angular and `@angular-builders` major versions should match.**

Solved by updating `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` to the latest version:

`npm install @angular-builders/custom-webpack@^12.0.0`

---

If, after doing the installation, you get an error like:
`An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'webpack'`, try removing `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and doing a clean install.

---

Github issue: https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/981

Answer (score 12):

Upgrade from `@angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100` to `@angular-devkit/build-angular@12`

Answer (score 9):

Try to remove

> "aot": true

from angular.json

Comment: Your solution worked for me but it was so weird, I just removed `aot` from build object and it effected on my `ng serve` command!

Comment: its working, idk how

Answer (score 1):

I'm still seen this error on @angular/core@12.0.3

The simple solution is to upgrade @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.xxx to @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.0.3.

The main point is to replace @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.xxx with @angular-devkit/build-angular@whatever_version_of_angular_you_have_installed in package.json.
After that delete "node_modules" folder and do "*npm install*"

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my app to Angular 11 and had same build errors. This issue fixed for me when I downgraded below package in package.json file.

From:

`"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.17",
}`

To:

`"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.2",
}`